# Rearrangement of absolutely convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-verification, solution-verification

I would be very grateful if someone would verify whether my proof below is correct.

Many thanks.

**Theorem.** $\,$ Let $(b_k)$ be a rearrangement of the complex sequence $(a_k)$. If $\sum_{k\geq 0}a_k = s$ and is absolutely convergent, then $\sum_{k\geq 0}b_k = s$.

*Proof.* $\,$ Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Choose $n\geq 0$ such that

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty|a_k|<\varepsilon.$$

Choose $N\geq 0$ such that

$$\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}\subseteq\{b_1,\ldots,b_N\},$$

Then, for any $m\geq N$, we have that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k-\sum_{k=0}^mb_k=\sum_{k\in A_m}a_k.$$

where $A_m=\{n+1,n+2,\ldots\}\setminus\{\text{finitely many points}\}$.

Hence, for any $m\geq N$, it follows that

$$\left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k-\sum_{k=0}^mb_k\right|\leq\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty|a_k|<\varepsilon.$$

This is what we were required to prove.

Comment: Do you mean $N$ instead of $m$ perhaps?

Comment: where do you mean, sorry?

Comment: In your sums, the upper limit of summation is $m$.

Comment: @AdamHughes: it is given that $m\ge N$.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I choose $m\geq N$ - does that answer your query? :)

Comment: Oops, thanks @robjohn, I missed that bit!

Comment: So is it ok now? :)

Comment: @user188071: it looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the proof you've provided is correct.

Comment: As an aside, I'd like to note that the reason why questions like this filter back to the front page is because the site automatically serves old upvoted questions without upvoted answers back to the front every now and then, hoping to get an answer. I write this as a community wiki to not get any rep, but to indicate that this should be considered an answered question.